# Add specified comment pattern in c

Tags: c, eclipse, vim

I'm wondoring if there exists a function of a software tool which allows me to add empty comment pattern to the variables defined in methods in c, for example `/**...*/`

I've tried using eclipse and vim. The best I can do is to add just comments for functions at the begining. I'd like to know if I could add such pattern wherever I want.

I know that use short cut key like <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> can make a sentence as comment, but in the format of `//`. If there's a way for me to change this format to the one I want, that would be also a great help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With [The NERD Commenter](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1218), you can surround a selected text or variable with command delimiters via its `<Leader>cc` mapping:

> ```
> [count]<Leader>cc NERDComComment
> Comment out the current line or text selected in visual mode.
> ```

With

```
let NERDComInsertMap='<c-c>'
```

you can define an insert mode mapping that inserts the comment prefix and suffix at the current position, and puts the cursor in between. The comment syntax is filetype-specific and can be configured via the `'commentstring'` option.

---

To change the comment prefix / suffix, you have to customize the plugin (in your `~/.vimrc`), as described by `:help NERDCustomDelimiters`, e.g. for Java:

```
let g:NERDCustomDelimiters = {
    \ 'java': { 'left': '/**', 'right': '*/' }
\ }
```

For unknown filetypes, you can also use `'commentstring'`, as this is what the plugin falls back to.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution. I spent a lot of time installing and enabling nerd comment, and I found out that the 'Append' option in 'comment' under "Plugin" could solve my problem. However the comment pattern appended is "/*..*/"

Comment: To change its format I'm pretty sure you explained that to me but I don't get it. I'm not clear about the command to do mapping you showed. And I don't find the option 'commentstring'. Could you give some an example of the using of the command? To change the format from "/*..*/" to "/**...*/"

Comment: It's a bit complicated indeed; I've added that to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination. But It seems that this "NERDCustomDelimiters" doesn't among the chapters in "Help". And in my vimrc I added the command above with 'c' taking place of 'java', nothing is changed.

Comment: For 'commentstring' I found sth in other sites, which is to use":set commentstring?" command. After typing that on the command line I see "commentstring = /*%s*/", and then I typed "/**%s*/" and there showed an error saying this pattern doesn't exist.

Comment: You would need `:set commentstring=/**%s*/`, but that only applies to NERDCommenter when it doesn't natively know the comment syntax (e.g. in a `:new` buffer without a filetype).

Answer (score 0):

In Notepad++ you can do that!

Check this [link](http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/Notepad-plus-plus_5.9.html)

In the web page search for **Comment / uncomment** section.